# How do I unlock skins?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have about 6 skins in my backpack that I can't unlock.  If I'm at a store and try to sell them, I can see them, but if I look in my inventory they aren't there.  Is there a specific place I have to go or thing to do in order to unlock them?

Comment: Is there red text on them in the item menu that says "already used" or something to that effect?

Comment: They aren't show up in you inventory?  Make sure you haven't filtered your inventory.

Comment: oh I filtered it at like the start of the game and didn't know it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if you were looking at your skins in the "buyback" menu at the store. they will be at that same store only for three game days.